# SQL Server Include user function result into select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this stored function

```
function GetPrevReading(
@utility int,
@asofdate datetime
) returns decimal(10,5)
```

This function returns the previous meter reading from the table with the following fieds:

```
utility - int
date - datetime
reading - numeric(18,4)
```

When I use select on this table I want to set a date as a parameter and get this from the table:

```
Utility    Previous Reading
(distinct) GetPrevReading(utility from query, @date from parameter)
```

I want the function GetPrevReading to take parameter 'utility' from the current row.
Is it possible to accompish this with a query or should I make a stored procedure?

For example, this is the table:

```
Utility    Date        Reading
1          2013-10-1   105.6
1          2013-11-1   123.72
2          2013-10-1   226.1
2          2013-10-1   238.18
```

Now, if I set parameter @date to 2013-10-29 I should get this result:

```
Utility    PreviousReading
1          105.6
2          226.1
```

Here, my function should get @utility=1 and @asofdate='2013-10-29' on the first row and @utility=2 and @asofdate='2013-10-29' on the second one.

Comment: Is this a scalar UDF that returns a single value? And wait, why is utility in the table an nvarchar(20), and the input to the function is an int?

Comment: My bad, Utility is int. I changed and yes, UDF is scalar

Comment: Is your reading numeric(18,4) or decimal(10,5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d4b0/1) out. I fixed some inconsistencies in your data types, and assumed that your last line of sample data really should have had 2013-11-01 as the date. Also, the way that the function is written, it's not getting the previous reading, but the reading on that date.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Utility Int,
    Date Date,
    Reading Decimal(10,5)
  );

INSERT INTO MyTable (Utility, Date, Reading)
VALUES
 (1,'2013-10-01', 105.60),
 (1,'2013-11-01', 123.72),
 (2,'2013-10-01', 226.10),
 (2,'2013-11-01', 238.18);

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetPrevReading(
  @utility int,
  @asofdate datetime
)
RETURNS Decimal(10,5)
AS
  BEGIN

    RETURN (
        SELECT TOP 1 Reading
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE Utility = @Utility
          AND Date = @asofdate
        ORDER BY Date DESC
      )
END;


SELECT
  Utility
  ,Date
  ,dbo.GetPrevReading(Utility, Date)
FROM (
  SELECT Utility, Max(Date) Date
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE Date < '2013-10-29'
  GROUP BY Utility
) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding the question; the function returns for this call

```
GetPrevReading( 1,2013-10-29)
```

Returns

```
1, 105.6
2, 226.1
```

And you want to join between the function and its results and the underlying table? You can do this in SQL 2005 + using the [Apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) join

```
Select 
…
From tblUtilityReadings
Cross Apply GetPrevReading(tblUtilityReadings.utility, @date)
```